# Why doesn't the <iframe seamless> property do what's expected?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe with a source defined and the sameless property added like:

```
<iframe src="http://myURL.com/sourceHTML.html" seamless></iframe>
```

The content displays in a small rectangle with a very small height and scroll bars. I thought it should show the entire amount of content. What's the deal?

update: image of what this looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a image to see how it looks like, I think I know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seamless attribute only removes the borders and scrollbars so that it looks like its part of the same document. I really don't recommend you to use that because only 3 major browser support that attribute. You can remove the borders and the scroll bar with CSS. Just add the code below between your  and

```
<style>
   iframe {
      border: none;
   }
</style>
```

Now the `div` that contains the `iframe` needs to be the same size as the content `div` that is on the page you want to display on the `iframe` for example if the width of the page to show on `iframe` is `600px` then the `div` that contains the `iframe` will also need to be `600px`

Comment: Thank you, for what I gathered I thought the seamless attribute literally puts the document in the correct size in the parent document. I guess not. I switched to using php include.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that `overflow` property does not exist in the `iframe` attributes.